# How to implement graceful shutdown for java ffmpeg processes inside SpringBoot app when receiving SIGINT?

Tags: spring-boot, ffmpeg, process, threadpool, shutdown

I am currently developing a SpringBoot version 2.6. 3 application.The app runs ffmpeg processes on thread pool executors like:

```
 @Bean(name = "ffmpeg")
 public TaskExecutor getAncaExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("ffmpeg-");
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(120);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;  
    }
```

```
@Autowired("ffmpeg")
TaskExecutor taskExecutor; 


public void transcode() {

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i input -y.......");
                result = process.waitFor(); 
                return result;
            }, taskExecutor).thenAccept(result -> handleResult());
            });
}
```

in my application.properties I have

```
server.shutdown=graceful
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=120s
```

When the app receives SIGINIT

1. ffmpeg gets killed of with 255 status code ( SIGINIT)
2. handle method is executed

Is there a way to wait a certain amount of time on those running ffmpeg processes to end, why does Spring Boot kills them off if taskExecutor has been with **setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);setAwaitTerminationSeconds(120);**

Comment: How are you sending `SIGINT` to your Spring Boot app? It sounds like the OS is sending this signal to the child processes too, possibly because they're all part of the same process group. That is something that is out of Spring Boot's control.

Comment: I am starting app as  mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local and then press CTRL+C.

Comment: That's the problem then. The OS will be propagating the signal to the child processes.